# Getting the current tab of a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom class called ATabBar that inherits from UITabBarController.

I have the following in my .m class:

```
- (void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger tab = self.tabBarController.selectedIndex;
}
```

It appears that never gets hit in debugging. How do I grab when a tab is clicked in a function in my tab bar?

Comment: Delegates... Have you checked?

Comment: add `<UITabbarControllerDelegate>` and `yourtabbarcontroller.delegate = self;` when alloc init tabbar.

Comment: Yep delegates! forgot to set tabcontroller.delegate = self;

Answer (score 0):

Managing the Selected Tab

```
selectedViewController (Property)

selectedIndex (Property)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/